# Internet Connection Sharing api for C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am totally new to C# and Windows application development. I wanted to enable Internet Connection Sharing using a Windows app. But when I searched for the APIs I got that it is only available for C, C++. I want to use those for my C# application as I have written most of my code in C#.

Please suggest any workaround if possible.

API Link:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364733(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -6):

you need to find the registry key of ICS and writing to it directly with C#:

[search it](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=find%20registry%20key%20of%20ICS&rlz=1C1GGGE___IN509IN509&oq=find%20registry%20key%20of%20ICS&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.5298&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)